# Changing application server key in push manager subscription

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, firebase-notifications

I implemented web push notifications using service worker. I collected user subscriptions with a particular application server key. Suppose if we change the application server key, then when we get the subscription using "reg.pushManager.getSubscription()", we will get the old subscription information which was created using the old application server key. How to handle this scenario? How to get the new subscription from the user?

Comment: check https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#dfn-push-subscription

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the subscription using `reg.pushManager.getSubscription()` and check whether current subscription uses the new application server key. If not, then call `unsubscribe()` function on the existing subscription and resubscribe again.

Comment: can you ellaborate on that? I can't understand exactly where can I get the subscription object.

Comment: take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription
(the example code)

Answer (score 5):

After properly starting the service worker and getting the permissions, call `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` in order to get access to the `*.pushManager` object.

From this object we call another promise to get the `pushSubscription` object we actually care about.

If the user was never subscribed `pushSubscription` will be `null` otherwise we get the key from it and check if it's different, if that's the case we unsubscribe the user and subscribe them again.

```
var NEW_PUBLIC_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    
Notification.requestPermission(function (result) {
    if (permissionResult == 'granted'){
        subscribeUser();
    }
});
    
function subscribeUser() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then(registration => {
        registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
        .then(pushSubscription => {
            if(!pushSubscription){
                //the user was never subscribed
                subscribe(registration);
            }
            else{
                //check if user was subscribed with a different key
                let json = pushSubscription.toJSON();
                let public_key = json.keys.p256dh;
                
                console.log(public_key);
                
                if(public_key != NEW_PUBLIC_KEY){
                    pushSubscription.unsubscribe().then(successful => {
                        // You've successfully unsubscribed
                        subscribe(registration);
                    }).catch(e => {
                        // Unsubscription failed
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    })
}

function subscribe(registration){
    registration.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(NEW_PUBLIC_KEY)
    })
    .then(pushSubscription => {
        //successfully subscribed to push
        //save it to your DB etc....
    });
}

function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
    var padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
    var base64 = (base64String + padding)
        .replace(/\-/g, '+')
        .replace(/_/g, '/');

    var rawData = window.atob(base64);
    var outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
        outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return outputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I managed to solve it by clearing the cache and cookies

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The key you get from calling `sub.getKey('p256dh')` (or `sub.toJSON.keys.p256dh`) is the client's public key, it will always be different from the server public key. You need to compare the new public server key and `sub.options.applicationServerKey`.

`sub` above is the resolved promise from `reg.pushManager.getSubscription()`.

Therefore:

1. Get PushSubscription interface - `reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then(sub => {...})`, if sub is null no subscription exists, therefore no worry, but if it's defined:
2. Inside the block get the current key in use `sub.options.applicationServerKey`
3. Convert it to string, because you can't compare ArrayBuffer directly - `const curKey = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(sub.options.applicationServerKey)))`
4. Compare it with your new key. If the keys are different call `sub.unsubscribe()` and then subscribe again by calling `reg.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions)`, where subscribeOptions uses your new key. You call 'unsubscribe' on PushSubscription, but `subscribe` on PushManager

Comment: curKey  key should be restored with replaced character, because of urlB64ToUint8Array function.
If you don't understand what it means look below link.
It makes you clear.
https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/web-push-codelab/blob/469a70b1eb195eeb27f5901ab58bd8452f015d9a/completed/07-unsubscribe/scripts/main.js#L32C10-L32C28

Answer (score 0):

This is real code for dealing with comparing application server key change.

I left more details how to deal it.
Previous answers were not enough to me.

```
function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = "=".repeat((4 - (base64String.length % 4)) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");

  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
}

function subscribe(registration) {
  registration.pushManager
    .subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(APPLICATON_SERVER_KEY),
    })
    .then(async function (pushSubscription) {
      //successfully subscribed to push
      //save it to your DB etc....
    });
}
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) {
  registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function (subscription) {
    if (!subscription) {
      return subscribe(registration);
    }

    const applicationServerKey = btoa(
      String.fromCharCode.apply(
        null,
        new Uint8Array(subscription.options.applicationServerKey)
      )
    );
    const currentKey = applicationServerKey
      .replaceAll("+", "-")
      .replaceAll("/", "_")
      .replaceAll("=", "");
    if (currentKey.indexOf(APPLICATON_SERVER_KEY) > -1) {
      console.log("Already subscribed");
      return subscription;
    } else {
      subscription
        .unsubscribe()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("subscribe again because of different key");
          return subscribe(registration);
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
          console.log("unsubscribed error", e);
        });
    }
  });
});
```

And when you change applicationServerKey, backend will get response 401 or 403 error from sending push message with endpoint.

So you need to deal it in serverside.

I am done it with this code.

```
for subscription in SubscriptionInfo.objects.all():
    try:
        send_to_subscription(subscription, payload)
    except Exception as e:
        if e.response.status_code == 403 or e.response.status_code == 401:
            subscription.delete()
        print(e)
        pass
```